# Get mongodb array count with less than and greater than

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to get array count among all documents that array content dates that less and greater than particular input given by me. I edited following query many ways but none of those won't get the result I expected.

```
db.user_log.aggregate(
      {$match: {"user_id" : "2"}}, 
      {$unwind: "$meta_data.access_times"},
      {$group: {_id: "$user_id", number: {$sum: 1 }}}
    )
```

above query give me sum of array count given user_id among all the documents. Result as follows.

```
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "number" : 26.0
}
```

How do I use gt and lt in above query?

my array -

```
"access_times" : [ 
            ISODate("2017-02-25T07:02:31.935Z"), 
            ISODate("2017-03-25T07:02:39.817Z")
        ],
```

I am going to made this array for mongo terminal and java

Comment: Can you add  sample document and expected json output ?

Comment: every document has a "meta_data.access_times" array. I need count of array elements that between two dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo terminal query

```
db.user_log.aggregate(
  {$unwind: '$meta_data.access_times'},
  {$match: {"user_id" : "2", "meta_data.access_times" : { $gt : ISODate("2017-03-23T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt : ISODate("2017-03-24T00:00:00.000Z")}}},
  {$group: {_id: null, 'sum': { $sum: 1}}},
  {$group: {_id: '$_id', total_sum: {'$sum': '$sum'}}}
)
```